# Adobe Flash How to change path after changing timeline etc (no tweens)

Tags: adobe-flash

How can i change the path of a layer/symbol. I've selected a path or form but can not change it because points to transform does not appear. Need to be possible or not ?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can double click the symbol to edit it. (Right clicking it and selecting "*Edit in place*" will do the same thing.) When you're done you can also double click the background to return to the previous view.